# Google Analytics: Engagement Flow doesn't show screen when using sendView: on iOS

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics in my iOS project.  I need to track several views in one UIViewController.
I use

> sendView:

each time the particular view is displayed in current viewController.

I also use the trackedViewName in GA-recommended way:

> -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
>
> ```
> //super viewDidAppear
> [super viewDidAppear:animated];
>
> //GAI
> self.trackedViewName = @"PAGE_DETAIL";
> ```
>
> }

Result:
When I open GA report and view Screens, the screen names are listed. But when I open Engagement Flow part in the report, the screens are not included in the Engagement Flow.

So on what condition screens will be included in Engagement Flow?
And how to make make one ViewController present several views in the Engagement Flow?

Thanks in advance a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Engagement flow need to be filled with a lot of request before it appears. Use the application from various devices a lot of times and you should see the flow.

Comment: Is there document or reference file mentioning about it?

Comment: No just experience, with few users I wasn't able to see it